# file exists in same folder but i keep getting the error file not found in vs code

Tags: python, pandas, excel

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\\Users\\psypa\\Documents\\python\\dev python\\CPI\\cpitest1.py", line 3, in \<module\>
dataframe1 = pandas.read_excel('book.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')
File "C:\\Users\\psypa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\io\\excel_base.py", line 478, in read_excel
io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
File "C:\\Users\\psypa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\io\\excel_base.py", line 1513, in __init__
self.\_reader = self.\_engines\[engine\](self.\_io, storage_options=storage_options)
File "C:\\Users\\psypa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\io\\excel_openpyxl.py", line 549, in __init__
super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)
File "C:\\Users\\psypa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\io\\excel_base.py", line 530, in __init__
self.handles = get_handle(
File "C:\\Users\\psypa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\io\\common.py", line 868, in get_handle
handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)
FileNotFoundError: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory: 'book.xlsx'
```

I want to read this Excel file and create a program around it but I keep getting the same error in VS code. I tried using the same code in pythons idle and it somehow works.*

**code:**

```
import pandas 

dataframe1 = pandas.read_excel('book.xlsx')

print(dataframe1)
```

**alternate version:**

```
import pandas

dataframe1 = pandas.read_excel('book.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')

print(dataframe1)
```

Comment: Try using the full path and file name `pandas.read_excel('drive:\path\to\book.xlsx')`

Comment: The Python interpreter does not have the same working directory as your script.

Comment: `import os; print(os.getcwd())` will show you the actual current working directory.

Comment: Thanks the above suggestions fixed the problem.